# hide page & subpages from menu

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following page structure in TYPO3:

```
- 1
  - 2
  - 3
- 4
  - 5
  - 6
- 7
  - 8
  - 9
```

Now I want to have 1/* + 4/* included in the header menu and 4/* + 7/* in the footer menu. Since the header and footer menus are different, I cannot just use the "hide in menu" feature and need to do it in TypoScript instead.

Here's what I have so far:

```
HEADERMENU = HMENU
HEADERMENU {
    1 = TMENU
    1.expAll = 1

    1.NO = 1
    1.NO {
        stdWrap.if.value.field = uid
        stdWrap.if.equals = 7
        stdWrap.if.negate = 1
    }

    2 < .1
}

FOOTERMENU < HEADERMENU
FOOTERMENU.1.NO.stdWrap.if.equals = 1
```

The problem with this is, that it still displays the pages 8+9 in the header and  2+3 in the footer, even if it does not display page 1/7 anymore. I know that I could use `if.isInList` and the provide all subpage IDs, but then I'd have to change the TypoScript everytime I add a new page. If possible, I'd like to dynamically exclude a page and all its subpages.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in his answer there is a way to display all subpages of the selected pages. `special = directory` displays however only the subpages. So you could see only `2/3` and `5/6` and `8/9` in your menus.

> special = directory
>
> "This will generate a menu of all pages with pid = 35 and pid = 56."

I would suggest the `excludeUidList` property.

```
HEADERMENU = HMENU
HEADERMENU {
    excludeUidList = 7
    1 = TMENU
    1.expAll = 1

    2 < .1
}

FOOTERMENU < HEADERMENU
FOOTERMENU.excludeUidList = 1
```

It is working as a `WHERE` condition in a db `SELECT` query, so you won't get those pages on the first level and neither will it find their subpages then.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: I am happy that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the `special=directory` approach to render a Menu of one or more pages and their subpages.

```
HEADERMENU.special = directory
HEADERMENU.special.value = 1, 4
```

More information in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-directory).